# Connecting PCA singular values to generating parameters

Tags: pca, independent-component-analysis

I have a non-linear function of the following form

**$y_i = f(x_i,\theta)$**

where $x_i$ is known and $\theta$ is a vector of parameters. I have generated $n$ realizations of $y_i$ by sampling from a distribution of my uncertainty on each $\theta$. I then perform PCA (I would like to investigate other forms of component analysis such as ICA as well) and get the singular values $\Sigma$ and the component vectors.

Is there a way to connect my generating parameters $\theta$ to the singular values? In other words, can I map from $\theta$ to $\Sigma$ and vice-versa?